# How to include "think-cell"-like percentage changes in a waterfall-chart generated in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, waterfall

I try to establish R as data visualisation tool in my company. A typical graph type used in my department are waterfall charts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart).

In R, there are some packages and hints for ggplot to generate a waterfall chart (https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/ggplot2-waterfall-charts/), which I used already.

Unfortunately, a common feature for the used waterfall charts are annotations with arrows to indicate the percentage changes within the steps.

See an example below:

[image: Percentage Change Annotations to a Bar / Waterfall Chart]

Or here in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMHf7uFR6Rk)

The software used to produce such kind of plots is think cell (https://www.think-cell.com/), which is an add-on to Excel and Powerpoint.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to start to tackle the topic. My first thoughts are going in this direction:

- Use geom_segment for generating the arrows and boxes
- Use ggplot's annotate funktion to place the text at the arrows or in the boxes
- Calculate the positions automatically based on the data provided to the waterfall chart.

May I ask you, if you have additional thoughts/ideas to implement such graphs in ggplot?

Best Regards Markus

Comment: I would approach this using a function to add the requisite layers to your plot, taking as parameters the source table, the start and end years, and perhaps something to specify the vertical offset. It could have these layers: 1) geom_segment with arrow; 2) ellipse (there might be one in ggforce?); 3) text box with something like paste0("CAGR\n", first_yr, "-", last_yr, "\n", [change_coefficient]^[1/years_elapsed] - 1 %>% [formatting_code])

Comment: 4 years have passed. Did you manage to find an easy to use alternative for think cell annotations? I have been looking for one since I left corporate but everything I ever found involves either paying for an addon of many lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the approach I would take.

#### Step 1. Pick which elements should be added, and add them one at a time.

Let's say we're starting with this simple chart:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(2007, 2008, 2009),
                 y = c(100, 120, 140))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

First of all, we need some extra vertical space:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = c(10, 50))) # Add 50 y padding
```

[image]

Now, I incrementally add layers until it looks like I want:

```
# Semi-manual proof of concept
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = c(10, 50))) + # Add 50 y padding

  # Line with arrow
  geom_segment(aes(x    = df$x[3], y    = df$y[3] + 50,
                   xend = df$x[3], yend = df$y[3] + 50), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc"), type = "closed")) +

  # Background box
  geom_tile(aes(x = mean(c(df$x[3], df$x[3])),
                y = mean(c(df$y[3], df$y[3])) + 50, width = 1, height = 40), 
            fill = "white", color = "black", size = 0.5) +

  # Text
  geom_text(aes(x = mean(c(df$x[3], df$x[3])),
                y = mean(c(df$y[3], df$y[3])) + 50,
                label = paste0("CAGR\n", 
                               df$x[3], "-", df$x[3], "\n", 
                               scales::percent((df$y[3] / df$y[3]) ^ (1/(df$x[3]-df$x[3])) - 1))))
```

[image]

#### Step 2. Make it into a function

Now I move the CAGR-related layers into a function, replacing most of the constants with function parameters.

```
add_CAGR <- function(df, first_val_pos, second_val_pos, 
                     y_offset, box_width = 1, box_height) {
  list(
    # Line with arrow
    geom_segment(aes(x    = df$x[first_val_pos], 
                     xend = df$x[second_val_pos], 
                     y    = df$y[first_val_pos]  + y_offset,
                     yend = df$y[second_val_pos] + y_offset), 
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc"), type = "closed")), 

      # Background box
      geom_tile(aes(x = mean(c(df$x[first_val_pos], df$x[second_val_pos])),
                    y = mean(c(df$y[first_val_pos], df$y[second_val_pos])) + y_offset, 
                    width = box_width, height = box_height), 
                fill = "white", color = "black", size = 0.5),

      # Text
      geom_text(aes(x = mean(c(df$x[first_val_pos], df$x[second_val_pos])),
                    y = mean(c(df$y[first_val_pos], df$y[second_val_pos])) + y_offset,
                    label = paste0("CAGR\n", 
                                   df$x[first_val_pos], "-", df$x[second_val_pos], "\n", 
                                   scales::percent((df$y[second_val_pos] / df$y[1]) ^ 
                                                     (1/(df$x[second_val_pos]-df$x[first_val_pos])) - 1))),
                lineheight = 0.8)
  )
}
```

#### Step 3: Use in plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = c(0, 50))) + # Add 50 y padding
  add_CAGR(df, first_val_pos = 1, second_val_pos = 3, 
           y_offset = 50,
           box_width = 0.7, box_height = 40)
```

[image]

Or the same thing just between the first two bars:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = c(0, 50))) + # Add 50 y padding
  add_CAGR(df, first_val_pos = 1, second_val_pos = 2, 
           y_offset = 50,
           box_width = 0.7, box_height = 40)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Jon, Thank you very much for your extensive answer. Best regards. Markus